# C++ how to work with a linked list whose datatype is a pair?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a linked list called:

LinkedList <std::pair <std::**string**, (class called **Process**)>> thelist;

So, the exact declaration is:

LinkedList **<**std::pair <std::**string**, **Process**>**>** thelist;

Suppose I have stored a series of **Process** inside thelist, and the first datatype of the pair (i.e. **string**) identifies what category of process it is. Let's say if the category is Stop, it stores the **Process** inside the list under Stop, and if the category is Resume: the **Process** is stored under Resume and so on.
My problem is, I am struggling to access the two types of data in pair for other methods I am required to implement. For example: I need to implement a method called Count_category( string category) that will count the number of Process inside the given category, but I can't figure out how to do so, as I don't know how to access the first datatype. I have figured out so far it can be accessed by doing like class.first and class.second, but can't figure out how I would use it in my case.
Help!!

I am including my linkedlist.hpp, if you need my class object that is used in the pair, let me know.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
        #ifndef LINKED_LIST_
        #define LINKED_LIST_
  
        #include <utility> //for swap
        #include <exception>
  
 #include "Node.hpp"
  
 template<typename T>
 class LinkedList
 {
 private:
    Node<T>* head; // Pointer to first node in the chain;
                             // (contains the first entry in the list)
    int count;           // Current count of list items 
    
    // Locates a specified node in this linked list.
    // @pre  position is the number of the desired node;
    //       position >= 1 and position <= itemCount.
    // @post  The node is found and a pointer to it is returned.
    // @param position  The number of the node to locate.
    // @return  A pointer to the node at the given position.
    Node<T>* getNodeAt(int position) const;
     void swap( LinkedList& lhs, LinkedList& rhs );
  
 public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& rhs);
    virtual ~LinkedList();
    LinkedList& operator=( LinkedList rhs );
  
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int get_count() const;
    bool insert(int newPosition, const T& newEntry);
    bool remove(int position);
    void clear();
    
    T getEntry(int position) const;
    T replace(int position, const T& newEntry);
  
 }; // end LinkedList
#endif

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````



##This is where I'm stuck: (it's in a different class called PManager that uses this Linked List);##


``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

int PManager::count_category(std::string category) const
{
int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= theList.get_count(); i++)
    {
        if (category == (this is where I need to access the category from the pair)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `std::map<std::string, std::vector<Process>>`? Then you can just ask `the_map["Stop"].size()` for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is exactly how I am supposed to implement it so I cant use a vector.

Comment: Then you need to show the interface of the `LinkedList` template. Without knowing its interface, we have no idea what operations it supports nor how to invoke them. Better, show the code you have so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok give me a minute while I figure out how to do so( I'm new to stack overlflow :) )

Comment: Added the hpp file

Comment: Wow, that's a terrible interface. Simple iteration from beginning to end is... am I reading this right?  Quadratic time complexity!?

Comment: Dont bother about the time complexity, its probably designed for beginners like me for understanding linked list.

Comment: Can you post all the restrictions you have been given? It almost sounds like the intention is to make something like `std::unordered_map` (which uses *multiple* linked lists)

Comment: @Genetarist There's nothing here that actually helps you understand a linked list... the underlying structure might as well be an array (unless you wrote the implementation yourself).

Comment: This is from a textbook, so I am sure they knew what they were doing and included it because it does help understand the basics of a linked list.  Yes, we were required to implement it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you get an element (or a reference to it) from LinkedList:

```
std::pair <std::string, Process> const& elem = llist.getEntry(0);
// now elem.first is a std::string
```

`elem` is a (reference to) `std::pair <std::string, Process>`. You can then use `elem.first` (which is a `std::string`) and `elem.second` (which is a `Process`).

Note that `getEntry` is inefficient: it returns a **copy** of the element in the list.

Comment: Where would I add this?? Also, I dont think I am allowed to use auto, do you have an alternate way?? I have posted the hpp file for the LInked List I'm using, see if that can be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Whith the interface you present it would be something like:

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList< std::pair< std::string, Process > > list;

    //... put in some data

    // count all elements in a given category

    std::string what{"Stop"};
    int found = 0;

    for ( int count = 0; count < list.get_count(); count++ )
    {
        std::pair< std::string, Process > element = list.getEntry( count );
        if ( element.first == what ) 
        {   
            found++;
        }   
    }

    std::cout << "Found " << found << " elements in category " << what << std::endl;
}
```

You LinkedList class has a very bad design because of:

- no iterators are present, so it can't be used with standard algorithms
- getter method returns a full copy,inefficient, no change of data possible
- access methods must iterate through all elements which is absolute unacceptable
- constructors did not allow to put data in
- no move construction
- insert only with given position, needs a lot of iterations, inefficient and complex to handle
- no front() and back() operators
- .... a lot more

If you use a stl compliant interface for your linked list, you can implement the functionality much easier. Only as an example for C++20:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class Process{};

int main()
{
    std::list< std::pair< std::string, Process > > l{ { "Stop", {} }, {"Resume",{}},{"Stop",{}}};
    std::string what{"Resume"};
    int found = std::ranges::count_if( l | std::views::keys , [&what]( const auto&s ){return s==what;} );
    std::cout << "Found " << found << " elements in category " << what << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be correct given I know the category of processes. But unortunately, the category will be generated during testing. I need to somehow access the value of **string** inside the pair to compare. Any more ideas??  [ I totally agree it is a bad design, this is just what is required for the assignment and I can't change it :(   ]

Comment: @Genetarist This does access the string and compare it, here: `element.first == what`. You can adapt this to a function where `what` is a parameter

Comment: @Genetarist Please try it out! It works, if your code works. It compares the content of your pair as I got from your explanation. Simply do it :-)

Comment: Yeah you are right, I would just like to clarify in case I was not clear on what I need to actually do. So when the category is == what in the get_category function, I need to count the number of process that are listed under what( Process itself is a class). So I don't count the total number of whats, I count the total number of processes listed under a single what. I guess your code achieves that, right??

Comment: @Genetarist: Yes! So simply try it out!

Comment: Okay, Thanks! If I still get stuck, I will probably post about it again.

Comment: Instead of "thank" you have the "upvote" and "accept" buttons. If the answer is helpfull, upvote please. If the answer is given all needed information, "accept" it. This is how SO works. Thanks!

Comment: @Klaus So I need help with one other function and I will be good to go. I will be posting about it shortly, would you mind taking a look? [P.S. I upvoted your answer but I got a message saying my response was recorded but won't be displayed as I have less than 15 reputation points. I guess I will need to keep posting to earn more points.]